# Why there are no constructor in servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I am studying servlets I read that servlets are java programs but there are no constructor in servlet...
Can anybody elaborate on it?

Comment: you read wrong, servers are not java programs, they are classes and every class has at least 1 constructor, even if it is the default no-arg constructor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are as in any other java class, but you don't need to invoke it. The webcontainer will call it for you.

Most servlets do not hold instance data, hence, most of adding code in the constructor doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to initialize your servlet you'll have to override the [init](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init%28javax.servlet.ServletConfig%29) method.

Answer (score 1):

There is a constructor in servlet (take a look at [HttpServlet](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.1/api/javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.html#HttpServlet()), for example), but usually the web container will take care of calling it for you.

However, when you are implementing a servlet, you normally are concerned with just overriding the `doGet()` and `doPost()` method (or the `service()` method, if you are working with other than `HttpServlet`)

Answer (score 0):

Ya we can definitely have constructor in servlet.Even you can use the constrctor in servlet for initialization purpose but this type of approch is not so common.You can perform common operations with the constructor as you normally do.The only thing is that you cannot call that constructor explicitly by the new keyword as we normally do.In the case of servlet servlet container is responsible for instentiating the servlet so the constructor is also called by servlet container only.

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely we can have a constructor inside the servlet but the only one disadvantage when we define a Constructor servlet cannot get the initial parameters and hence we use init() method to initialize a servlet.