# Why do people say that is not recommended using constructors on Servlets/SIP Servlets?

Tags: java, http, servlets, constructor, sip

This is just curiosity, I read on some posts that is not a recommended practice create constructors on Servlets, but to be honest I have no idea why they say that, there must be a reason because I know there's an `init()` method to initialize things, but why can't I use the constructor to do this?

Also the Eclipse Servlet wizard generated a constructor calling `super()` in it, and I'm not why is this super doing there

Thanks!

Comment: to do what? we can't see your code if you don't post it.

Comment: refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103479/why-there-are-no-constructor-in-servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not harmful, it's just never useful.  What can you do in a constructor of a class that has no access to external resources (these may not have been provisioned for the servlet yet), no access to container resources (also may not have been provisioned for the servlet), no access to configuration, no constructor arguments, etc.

Comment: Great answer, I guess this is true also for SIP Servlets, right?

Comment: I would guess so but I don't know anything about SIP servlets.